# How to use RAG with MultiPromptChain?

Tags: python, large-language-model, py-langchain

i have a requirement where i have 2 prompts and as per the User query any 1 of the prompt will be used this part i'm able to achieve with MultiPromptChain but now i want to RAG on this but i'm sure how to implement it. Attaching my code below:

```
sample_template_org="""xyz {query} """
sample_template_year="""xyz {query} """

prompt_infos = [
{
"name": "year",
"description": "Good for answering questions about year to year comparison for a company on the basis of common categories",
"prompt_template": template_year,
},
{
"name": "org",
"description": "Good for answering questions about company to company comparison on the basis of common categories",
"prompt_template": template_org,
},
]

destination_chains = {}
for p_info in prompt_infos:
name = p_info["name"]
prompt_template = p_info["prompt_template"]
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=['query'])
qa_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt)
destination_chains[name] = qa_chain
destination_chains
default_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm, output_key="text")

destinations = [f"{p['name']}: {p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)
router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(destinations=destinations_str)
router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
template=router_template,
input_variables=["input"],
output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
)
router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)

chain = MultiPromptChain(
router_chain=router_chain,
destination_chains=destination_chains,
default_chain=default_chain,
verbose=True,
)
```

Now i need to implement Retrieval over here so that after selecting the  correct chain as per the user query it will retrive relevant documents from vector db and use it.

I tried to implement RAG and MultiPromptChain together but its not working